# Radio Buttons are not applying style dynamically

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I'm trying to refresh a list of radio buttons every time a user visits the tab menu. First time visit styling is okay, but they are behaving like checkboxes and can not be unchecked when other radio buttons are clicked.

I have tried to put `refresh();` method but it still doesn't work.

You can see the demo on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w4gQa/1/)

Any suggestion? and Thank you.

```
$('.export_tab').click(function(){
    $("#radios_wrapper").children().remove(); //Remove all previous radio buttons
    for(var i in localStorage) //Looping through the localStorage
        {
            dataIndex = JSON.parse(localStorage[i]).index;
            dataName = JSON.parse(localStorage[i]).name;
                    //Then insert a new one
            $("#radios_wrapper").append('<input type="radio" value="'+dataIndex+'" name="'+dataIndex+'" id="radio'+dataIndex+'"/><label for="radio'+dataIndex+'">'+dataName+'</label>');
        }
});
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id='radios_wrapper'>

     </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide a demo: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w4gQa/1/ Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Radiobuttons need the same name to become a group. So:

```
'<input type="radio" value="'+dataIndex+'" name="'+dataIndex+'"/>'
```

is not the right way. The name should be the same for all radios you want to group. It should be:

```
'<input type="radio" value="'+dataIndex+'" name="allTheSame"/>'
```

Here is an update to your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4gQa/2/).

To tell jQuery to redraw use the trigger function like `.append('whatever').trigger('create')`. http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html. Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4gQa/4/).

Comment: I have tried. It's still not working. See the demo here.
http://jsfiddle.net/w4gQa/1/

Comment: @PakinaiKamolpus: Your fiddle does not what I said. See my update.

Comment: Okay. but they are still not apply the style.

Comment: Style? I can't see any styling code in your post or in your fiddle.

Comment: It should be apply the JQM default style.
Like this. http://jsfiddle.net/w4gQa/3/

Comment: I see. I updated my answer and your fiddle. Maybe that helps.